# Convert DateTime to yyyyMMdd int

Tags: c#, datetime

What is the quickest way to convert a DateTime to a int representation of the format yyyyMMdd.

i.e. 01-Jan-2007 --> 20070101 (as in int)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
int x = date.Year * 10000 + date.Month * 100 + date.Day
```

Comment: @Steve: Well, the most straightforward that came to my mind ;). The format string variant just makes things a little clearer for someone only casually glancing at the code.

Comment: Nice option for this.  Very clean way to handle it.

Comment: this is really nice, but might not be that obvious/clear to someone coming across it in the future?

Comment: @msulis: That's probably a good job for a comment. However, glancing at this for more than half a second should reveal the meaning, I guess. After all, I just looked at it and understood it again after re-reading it once – and I wrote that line a few months ago.

Answer (score 15):

```
int result = int.Parse(myDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Comment: +1, I would just add you might want to do a TryParse, just to be safe.

Comment: so it is required to first convert the DateTime to a string, then to an int? Thanks for your code, i was unaware of int.Parse

Comment: @Phillis: No, it's not required. But above code shows better what exactly is going on, though.

Comment: @JackM - This would be a rare case where TryParse is unnecessary as there is no way the format string will ever result in a non-integer.

Comment: Yes - here you KNOW the format, in advance, so it's safe to avoid.  Johannes's answer is better, though.